# Which URL to enter into browser to show all posts in archive.php?

Tags: posts, archives

Consider the simplest `archive.php` possible:

```
<?php

get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
}

get_footer();
```

**What address should I type into the browser to get to this page and display all posts?** The permalink Custom Struction is set as "/%category%/%postname%/". I have tried going http://example.com/posts but that page returns simply a 404 error.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for: `example.com?post_type=post&cat=category-slug` ?

Comment: @admcfajn: No. I would like the page to display all posts, regardless of post type or category.

Answer (score 2):

`archive.php` is very broad template, possibly used for many kinds of archives.

If you mean common reverse chronological view the link to that would be return of [`get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) for the specific post type.

Note that the native `post` post type is special case. For it archive is typically either site root or posts page, depending on site's configuration. Those *never* use `archive.php`, according to [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Comment: It is exactly because `archive.php` is a broad template that I would prefer to use it. The `archive.php` _file_ is called for many _different URLs_, such as `http://example.com/foo_type/`, `http://example.com/foo_category/`, `http://example.com/foo_tag/`, `http://example.com/foo_date/`, etc. But which URL should be used to get an archive of all the posts?

Comment: Had you read my answer? If you mean `post` type posts — they will never use `archive.php` template for main archive.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying my position, I did not want to seem contradictory. In fact, `post` type posts _do_ use `archive.php` when the URLs mentioned in the above comment are called. However, each of those URLs applies a filter to The Loop behind the scenes, limiting the returned posts to only a specific category, tag, date, etc. I need to know the URL address to use which will not apply any filter. **I agree that this case is not addressed in the Template Hierarchy wiki page.**

Comment: Again, this is covered in the answer — archive for _all_ of `post`s will be site root or posts page (depending on Settings > Reading > Front Page Displays). It _won't_ use `archive.php` because it's in a different branch of template hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Perhaps `home.php` would be a good alternative, seeing how it is labeled "Blog posts index page". **What URL would one type into the browser to get to `home.php`?**

Comment: Likely no path `example.com/` or path to posts page configured in settings `example.com/name-of-posts-page/`

Answer (score 0):

The URL for `archive.php` to list all posts **which do not have a category** assigned is:

> **http://example.com/uncategorized/**

This can be found be going to any post which has not been assigned a category, and examining the URL. Just remove the post slug to arrive at the relevant archive:

> http://local.example.com/uncategorized/hello-world/

Comment: This does not display _all_ posts though.